# How do I change program starting from starting from onload to starting from Space press?

Tags: javascript

I want to change game from starting from onload to onkeydown (space) but I dont know how to put entire code under onkeydown command. I am amatour in programming and this is one of my very first projects so thanks for help :)

```
<body onload="startGame()">



<script>





function startGame() {

myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
start : function() {
    this.canvas.width = 220;
    this.canvas.height = 400;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
this.frameNo = 0;
updateGameArea();
    },
clear : function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
} 

}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
this.type = type;


function everyinterval(n) {
    if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
    return false;
}

function accelerate(n) {
    if (!myGameArea.interval) {myGameArea.interval = 
setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);}

    myGamePiece.gravity = n;
}

function reload()
{
    window.location.reload(true);
}
document.onkeydown = function(event)
{
    if(event.keyCode === 27)
        paused = !paused;
}


</script>

<button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.2); myMusic.play();" 
onmouseup="accelerate(0.05)">szybuj :')</button>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sidka/k1f4ow0q/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `onload="startGame()"`. Add `keypress` event to your document and check it's `keyCode` for space i:e `32`.

```
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 32) {
        startGame();
    }
});
```

```js
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 32) {
      console.log('spacebar');
    }
});
```

```html
<p> Press spacebar </p>
```

Comment: It works great thanks, but I wonder what do I do if I want to have one photo, which is static and then after keypress (Space) it disappears and actual game shows?

Comment: Hide the `img` by setting its display property to none. Place the code above the call of `startGame();`.

Comment: But if I give `img` display propery none it wont show at all from the beginning no?

Comment: Set it's display property to none inside the block where did you called your `startGame();`. `if(e.keyCode == 32) { document.querySelector('img').style.display="none"; startGame(); }`

Comment: Sorry for asking again but do you know how to make random background (not the one which is made as img but the myBackground to be one of 2 randomly)? jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sidka/k1f4ow0q/6/

Comment: You mean you want to display random background img? Yes. You can get the length of total number of images you have, then get the randomIndex using `Math.floor(Math.random() *  length_of_images + 1);` and load the image of that specific index.

Comment: Ok and the very last question(now truly). `myScore` is set to be a component which displays on `(90, 40)` dimensions and I would like to (when there is `crashWith myObstacle`) change its height (to be on the +-middle of the screen). How can I do it?

Comment: I'am not really sure about what does `crashWith myObstacle` mean?

Comment: if you open my file in jsFiddle this is where collision with objects happens and i want to (when you collide) to move the score in +- middle of the game to show final score.